# Keras : TypeError: 'AddNL' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I am using Keras Functional API, with TensorFlow backend, to define Convolutional Layers and I have to implement a custom `merge` layer.

Assuming:

```
# All necessary libraries imported.
# image_shape = (28, 28, 3)
# 16 and (3,3) are kernel_count and kernel_size respectively.
def MyModel(image_shape):
    input = Input(shape=image_shape)
    conv1 = Conv2D(16, (3,3), kernel_initializer='he_normal')(input)
    conv2 = Conv2D(16, (3,3), kernel_initializer='he_normal')(input)
    conv3 = AddNL()[conv1, conv2]
```

where my custom merge layer `AddNL` is implemented in the `keras.layers.merge` as following:

```
class AddNL(_Merge):
    def _merge_function(self, inputs):
        nK1 = inputs[0].shape[-1]
        nK2 = inputs[1].shape[-1]
        # <?, image,image, channel> Channel = Number of Kernels.
        k = nK1 if nK1 < nK2 else nK2
        output = input[0][...,0:k] + input[1][...,0:k] 
        return output
```

When my code reached the line, the following `TypeError` is  thrown:

`TypeError: 'AddNL' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`

Comment: Shouldn't it be: `conv3 = AddNL([conv1, conv2])`?

Comment: @MarcinMożejko Ahh. It should be.

Comment: So may I formulate an answer then?

Comment: Of course. Why ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a typo. The code should look like following:

```
conv3 = AddNL([conv1, conv2])
```

Comment: I have a question though, Keras documentation and code suggests the use of the following syntax: `AddNL()([conv1, conv2])`, is there a difference between your syntax and keras's suggested one?